# How to invoke method of one class in another class using @Inject?

Tags: java, methods, dependency-injection, inject

Suppose there are two classes, Class A and Class B. Class A has main() in it while Class B has some business methods. In the simplest way using new operator in Class A, Class B along with its methods can be accessed. Now if we are to do the same thing using @Inject how can it be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes my mistake, should be.@Inject

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `main()` method will have to set up your dependency injection framework of choice, configuring it to know how to instantiate instances of `A` and `B`.

Then it should request the framework to create an instance of `A`. The framework will, if properly set up, create an instance of `A` with an instance of `B` injected.

And so this `A` instance will be able to call methods on the injected `B` instance.